# Ubuntu 13.10 has problem installing from source, due to "gazebo2" package, does it really exist?

Tags: ros, gazebo, wstool, rosinstall, desktop-full

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

when i try to install on Ubuntu 13.10 ROS Medusa-hydro full from source, while running :

$ rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro hydro --deps --wet-only --tar > hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
$ wstool init -j8 src hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall

wstool claim about a problem with a gazebo2 package.
Can you please help me? any suggestion?

I've checked in .rosinstall and i've found no package with that name....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135326/ubuntu-13.10-has-problem-installing-from-source,-due-to-%22gazebo2%22-package,-does-it-really-exist?/) by [RiccardoLasagno](https://answers.ros.org/users/12766/riccardolasagno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a open bug until there is a stable build of gazebo2 for Ubuntu 13.10.

In the meantime, there are a few solutions here: http://answers.ros.org/question/129616/error-while-building-catkin_ws-in-ubuntu-1310/ and a suggestion to install the beta gazebo2 package manually by the gazebo developers: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/2906#issuecomment-35412728

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiccardoLasagno](https://answers.ros.org/users/12766/riccardolasagno/) on 2014-03-04**:
Thank you for the suggestion

just for my understanding, since I'm new in ROS: if i use rosdep check, then rosdep install will install only dependancies that can be satisfied?

Thank you for your answer

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-04**:
rosdep check will tell you which dependencies are missing, but it won't install them for you. It will not change the behavior of rosdep install.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-03-04**:
You can run the `rosdep install ...` command with the `--simulate` option and it will print the commands it would have run, then you can copy and paste the ones you want, i.e. all of them except the gazebo one.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-03-04**:
Also there is a proposed pull request to allow the explicit ignoring of dependencies: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/301